# How often the math.random() and other RNG functions work?

Tags: javascript

So I just recently started coding, and I have a question about the RNG functions, like Math.random(). How often do they go off? Everytime a need a value from it, will it produce another number. For example, in

```
var num1; 
num1 = Math.random();
alert(num1)
num1 = Math.random();
alert(num1);
```

would the two JS alerts have different numbers? Same when using something like

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

instead of using Math.random() in the above program.

Comment: Ask yourself this as well: will your code show one alert? Or will it alert every time you call `alert`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. In your case, it is just a matter of trying. Yes they provide a new number each time.

Comment: Every time when you call `Math.random()` you will get random number. At your first example you will get 2 of those. Your second function will still rely on `Math.random()` and knowing the algorithm you can get original random value.

Comment: @Luaan, thx for the update. guess there isn't:)

Answer (score 1):

The specification for `Math.random` says this:

> Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no arguments.

So it doesn't explicitly address the question - but that's an answer in itself. It's a function that returns a random number when you call it. The only thing that makes sense is to be safe for multiple consecutive calls. Indeed,

```
Math.random() == Math.random()
```

will (almost) always return false, as expected. It's possible for implementations to give different results, yes - but you'd be hard pressed to find a pseudo-random generator that doesn't return different values when called from the same thread over and over.

"Approximately uniform distribution" basically means that `return 0.3` is not a conforming implementation, regardless of how fair a dice throw led to that constant. It also means that it's perfectly possible for two consecutive calls to return the *same* number - it just isn't very likely :)

Answer (score 1):

Math.Random is simply a function that gives a random number. It has no memory to save the numbers already generated hence there is no guarantee that duplicate number wont be generated although, chances are very low.

In second example of yours a random number will be generated between min to max, including min and max.